# Having troubles to send mails in 1and1 hosting

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I have a 1and1 account, im trying to send emails with symfony2.3 and swift_mailer but it is impossible.

I'm not having any error, i already check the symfony logs, but nothing.

This is my implemtation(in a Action):

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('test@domain.com')
    ->setTo('myuser@mydomain.com')
    ->addCc('other@mydomain.com')
    ->setBody( "test body" )
;
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
$result = $mailer->send($message, $fails);

//$fails receive a empty array
//$result get value 1
```

This is the configuration:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp                  #i also try mail and sendmail
    host:      smtp.1and1.mx         #i also try smtp.1and1.es, auth.smtp.1and1.fr
    username:  someone@mydomain.net  #the complete email someone@mydomain.net(this account is active, i'm able to login in webmail...) 
    password:  mypass
    spool:     { type: memory }
    encryption: tls                  # i also try without this setting
```

Nothing work, even, i try with gmail configuration:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    host:      smtp.gmail.com    #with and without this parameter
    username:  %mailer_user%     #the complete email someone@gmail.com and without domain
    password:  %mailer_password% #the gmail password
```

and same result.

What im doing wrong?
1and1 support just send me this link:

```
http://faq.1and1.es/email/email/informacion_email/9.html
```

**Update:**

If i remove { type: memory } in the configuration i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.1and1.es [Connection refused #111]...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6):

Instead mail.php, go to .env and set MAIL_DRIVER property. This work on 1and1.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.1and1.es
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=<xxxxxx@xxxx>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<xxxxxx>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

We had issues with Swiftmailer not sending emails when using the memory spool.  We ended up changing to a file spool and then setting up a cron job to execute the swiftmailer command to send it out (`app/console swiftmailer:spool:send -e=prod`)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: deleted tard answer and added this other one:

If your SMTP password contains @ symbol it can cause the .env file to fail if you don't use quotes

Comment: This answer :
- concerns Laravel 5 specific config and not Symfony2/3 config,
- uses the PHP dotenv library, but Symfony does not,
- is a bad usage of the PHP dotenv library, as you should not change the default value of your config files, but edit the .env file at your projects root instead,
- forces the mail to be sent via the PHP mail() method, which is a bad practice for massive bulks mails (one socket per mail)
- assumes the PHP function would work on any system with any configuration, which might be wrong

Comment: You're right. I'll leave this answer here for people to know this error.